# Figuring out velocity from an angle

Tags: c#

I know how to produce the rotation from a velocity, which I believe is somewhat along the lines of this

```
thing.rotation = Math.Atan2(thing.velocity.Y, thing.velocity.X);
```

However, would there be a way to produce a velocity based on the rotation? I think a shorter way of putting this would be to say, is there an effective inverse of Atan2, which instead returns a Vector2 instead of a double? Thanks.

Comment: you can get a vector from an angle, but it will always be of length 1

Comment: Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: the velocity has two components, x and y. when you transform it to an angle, it looses a bit of information, the length of the velocity vector. the angle can only yield a vector of length 1, which you can then scale by the length of the velocity vector you had previously.

Comment: Ah I see. So, if that were to be put in code, would it be::
thing.velocity.X = (1 - p.rotation) * scale; ?

Comment: From an angle, you can get the x by doing `cos(angle)` and y with `sin(angle)`

Comment: I have seen that they may be related to what I'm looking for, though I'm not an extremely experienced programmer, especially not in the maths side of things.

Comment: I also did brush across those, I wasn't sure if they were the answer to my query, I will do a quick check now. Thank you. EDIT: Keep getting more comments while typing my own. I will look over that page now, thanks!

Comment: This seems like more of a math question than a C# coding question.  There's always http://math.stackexchange.com/ for this type of question.

Comment: Oh, I had never noticed that. I will use that in the future. Thanks for the help all, I have a better understanding of the topic now :)

Comment: I am sure people here can handle 9th grade maths quite well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given an angle, you can produce a `Vector2` via:

```
new Vector2(Math.Cos(angle), Math.Sin(angle));
```

This will give you a vector of unit length. You should multiply by the magnitude of your velocity to get your proper velocity vector:

```
Vector2 velocity = new Vector2(speed * Math.Cos(angle), speed * Math.Sin(angle));
```

This will allow you to create a velocity vector for a given speed for any arbitrary angle.

Note that two parameters are required: the angle and magnitude that you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can't revert that, in this group (atan2, x, y) you always need to know 2 parameters to find out the 3rd one.

Answer (score 0):

You might be thinking of the speed as a complex number with rectangular coordinates (x, y) and tranform it to polar coordinates (ro, theta):

```
double theta(double x, double y) { return atan2(y, x); }
void ro(double x, double y) { return sqrt(x*x + y*y); }
```

Now the speed is expressed in terms of modulus (ro) which indicates its magnitude, and an angle theta that indicates its direction.

The inverse transformation is given by:

```
double X(double ro, double theta) {return ro * cos(theta); }
double Y(double ro, double theta) {return ro * sin(theta); }
```

Since you are working in an OOP language, it would be surely better to use or create a class for complex numbers, it is a powerful tool for dealing with plane geometry.